# Why does any input return the first conditional in this function?

Tags: javascript

my function below needs to take in a string, and then return whether it is a number, not a number or empty.

I've been working and staring at this all day - when I test it, it always executes the first conditional "Is a number" no matter what I input into the function, and I'm completely baffled as to why. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
function validateInput(testInput) {
    if (typeof parseInt(testInput) === 'number') {
    return "Is a Number";
    } else if (isNaN(parseInt(testInput)) === true) {
    return "Not a Number";
    } else if (testInput === "") {
    return "Empty";
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `parseInt` will always return something of type `"number"`. Read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt). Please try using the [debugging capabilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript) of your browser. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`). Try `console.log(parseInt("not a number", 10), typeof NaN);`.

Comment: `parseInt()` always returns a "number" (even `NaN`)

Comment: `parseInt()` won't tell you if something is a number: `parseInt("123-not-a-number")` returns `123`

Comment: Test `typeof testInput === "number" && !isNaN(testInput)` directly; after all, you say _“Is a number”_. If you want to test if it’s either a number _or a string that can be converted to a number_, then use `(typeof testInput === "number" || typeof testInput === "string")` before the `&&`. It all depends on what you’re actually trying to test. There’s no clear specification of what your function shall do.

Answer (score 0):

You are using parseInt(testInput), it will be converted to a numeric type format.
Remove the parseInt and it will update.

Answer (score 0):

`parseInt` returns `NaN` if the string cannot be converted to a number. `typeof NaN`, however, is `"number"`. You can restructure your conditions to do the more specific tests first:

```
function validateInput(testInput) {
    if(testInput === "") return "Empty";
    if(isNaN(testInput)) return "Not a Number";
    return "Is a Number";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`parseInt('foo')` will return NaN, which despite standing for "Not a Number" [has a type of number](https://medium.com/swlh/javascript-is-weird-554c3dac0c98).

[Also somewhat relevant](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat).

Answer (score -1):

```js
function validateInput(testInput) {
    if (testInput == "")
    {
      return "Empty";
    }
    else if (!isNaN(parseInt(testInput)))
    {
      return "Is a Number";
    }
    return "Not a Number";
}

const span = document.querySelector('span');
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', function()
{
  span.innerText = validateInput(this.value);
});
```

```html
<input type="text">
<br>
<span></span>
```